# C# CRM SDK Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, sdk, connection, crm

I have the server URI, the port, username and the password. Knowing all this stuff, how can I simply connect to a CRM server using Microsoft's own SDK? I am using .NET Framework 4.

Although I have analyzed their gigantic ServerConnection class, I unfortunately did not manage to find that one particular line that simply does the connecting.

Comment: On-Premise or Online environment ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I develop it as a Windows Form application.

Comment: `CRM On Premise` means you have your own CRM setup on your server, `CRM Online` is hosted in the cloud: development can be quite different.

Comment: Well, I have my own Microsoft CRM setup, which is not on the client machine, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN provides very helpful samples for performing CRUD operations both via early and late binding:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328499.aspx - Early binding
Code available in the SDK under \SampleCode\CS\GeneralProgramming\EarlyBound\CRUDOperations.cs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309272.aspx - Late binding
Code available in the SDK under \SampleCode\CS\GeneralProgramming\LateBound\CRUDOperationsDE.cs